# unable to upload csv file in database

Tags: php

I have an uploads page where a user can upload CSV files only. However, when i hit the upload button, nothing is uploaded to my database and no error messages are displayed. Only the go back button shows which means that my code must not be executing my code properly. How would i resolve this?

I tried below code but nothing is loaded into my database.No error msg is there.When try the upload.php code but it fail to load the csv file into database.

a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
 echo("success");

mysql_select_db("a", $con);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];





                  $sql1 = $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$tmp."' INTO TABLE `a.demo` FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'# 10 rows affected.\n"
    . "";



       mysql_query($sql1,$con);  



    }else{
        echo 'Failed  uploaded files';
    }


?>
```

Comment: Seems the Query is wrong.Can you please explain whether you want to save the uploaded csv file path in server or you want to process the csv and store the csv data in db.

Comment: i want to store the content of csv data into the db

Comment: I have added the code  in the answer, please follow that and according to your need modify.if it is helpful please accept it as an answer give your valuable vote.If it is not helpful please let me know what the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

@Dipti As you need to upload a `csv file` and import the `csv data` to table.You may follow the below code for your reference.Assumed the each row of the csv file content `three` columns like col1,col2,col3.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//It is advisable to use mysqli
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo("success");
    }

    $upload_dir = 'uploads/';//Where you want to save the CSV file for future use.
    $upload_file = $upload_dir . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $upload_file)) {
        $i=0;
        $uploadMessage = "";
        $file = fopen($upload_file,"r");
        while(!feof($file))
        {
            $i++;
            $dataLine = fgets($file);
            $dataArray = explode(",",$dataLine);

            //validate the CSV file.If number of columns in the csv file is not 3 then ignore the line.
            if($count($dataArray) == 3){    
                //Get each column data
                $col1 = $dataArray[0];
                $col2 = $dataArray[1];
                $col3 = $dataArray[2];
                //Continue Like This(if number field is more) and User your Table Name and Column as per your DB table.
                $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO table_name SET column_1 = '".$col1."',column_2 ='".$col2."',column_3 ='".$col3."'";
                if(mysql_query($sqlQuery)){
                    $uploadMessage .= "<br/>Sucess, Row ".$i ." is inserted into DB successfully";
                }else{
                    $uploadMessage .= "<br/> Erroe, Row ".$i ." is Not inserted into DB successfully ".mysql_error();
                }
            }else{
                $uploadMessage .= "Line number ".$i ." Is Invalid format.";
            }
        }
        echo "File data Imported to DB with following message <br/>".$uploadMessage;
        fclose($file);

    }else{
        echo "File is not Uploaded Successfully";
    }   
?>
```